# Swapping in classes on 2 buttons Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

A little confused how I would add a Active effect to 2 different items using jquery.

Im using w3schools Vertical Tabs tutorial for this, But I have 2 tabbing "Links"

```
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'PRO')" id="defaultOpen">1</button>
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'CREAT')" id="defaultOpen">2</button>
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'TIM')" id="defaultOpen">3</button>


<button class="tablinks-title" onclick="openTab(event, 'PRO')" id="defaultOpen">A tittle</button>
<button class="tablinks-title" onclick="openTab(event, 'CREAT')">Another Title</button>
<button class="tablinks-title" onclick="openTab(event, 'TIM')">One More</button>
```

```
   function openTab(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks, tabnumber;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks-title");
        tabnumber = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks-title");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            tabnumber[i].className = tabnumber[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

    }

    // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

So the idea is to add the active class to both the number and the title 
when the one is active .

So if 1 is active a tittle should also have the active class.

Not to sure how i'd achieve this.

Update for Ryan:

```
<div class="side-tab col-md-2">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="tab-number col-md-6">
      <button class="tablinks lightnumber1" onclick="openTab(event, 'PRO')" id="defaultOpentitle">01</button>
      <button class="tablinks lightnumber" onclick="openTab(event, 'CREAT')">02</button>
      <button class="tablinks lightnumber" onclick="openTab(event, 'TIM')">03</button>
  </div>
    <div class="tab-title col-md-6">
        <button class="tablinks-title highlight1" onclick="openTab(event, 'PRO')" id="defaultOpen">PROFESSIONAL</button>
        <button class="tablinks-title highlight" onclick="openTab(event, 'CREAT')">CREATIVITY</button>
        <button class="tablinks-title highlight" onclick="openTab(event, 'TIM')">TIMELY</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="TabbedContent col-md-10">
        <div id="PRO" class="tabcontent">
            <?php
            echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider=3]');
            ?>

        </div>

        <div id="CREAT" class="tabcontent">
            <?php
            echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider=4]');
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="TIM" class="tabcontent">
            <?php
            echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider=5]');
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");` .......there is no element with class *tabcontent*!!!

Comment: You're also repeating the same id (`id="defaultOpen"`) on multiple elements which is invalid. `id` attribute values need to be unique within the DOM

Comment: Noted Rory thank you! And mamun I just dint add the content in the question as the switching is working fine

Comment: Use the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) interface instead of manipulating the `className` value as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your button for number and your button for title coincide, you can use the index like so:

```
function openTab(evt, cityName) {
    let buttonIndex = -1;
    const $clickedButton = $(evt.target); //Using Jquery to get the button which was clicked
    const tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

 if($clickedButton.hasClass('tablinks')){
     $('.tablinks').each(function(i, el){ 
         if($(el).is($clickedButton)){
            buttonIndex = i;
            return false; //break from the each now that we have the button index
         }
     });
 } else {
     $('.tablinks-title').each(function(i, el){ 
         if($(el).is($clickedButton)){
            buttonIndex = i;
            return false; //break from the each now that we have the button index
         }
     });
 }

 //Remove active class from buttons before adding to newly selected
 $('.tablinks').removeClass('active');
 $('.tablinks-title').removeClass('active');

 //Add the active class to the corresponding buttons at the clicked index for both
 //Number and title
 $($('.tablinks')[buttonIndex]).addClass('active');
 $($('.tablinks-title')[buttonIndex]).addClass('active');

 document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the tabs to swap but not the classes to be added getting this for .addClass() 

"Unresolved function or method addClass() 
 Inspection info: Checks that called functions are valid. The validation works in JavaScript, html or jsp files"

Comment: @Someguy Try it with my edit. I set the clickedButton constant to `evt.target` as a Jquery object.

Comment: Quick Question Ryan how would u Set it so that only 1 is active on the first open I see that it starts with all 3 being open

Comment: the content I mean

Comment: @Someguy, I'm unsure of what you mean. Can you clarify more on your most recent question?

Comment: with the content when I open the page I have all 3 contents visible, not a default or just one, like I have 3 content tabs and all 3 are open when you open the page

Comment: @Someguy Can you add the HTML which shows these `contents` to your post please?

Comment: @Someguy Just set all three `content` divs style to `display:none` in your `HTML`, when your function is called it will show the content div associated with the active buttons.